# Set items in localStorage on second web session/after refreshing

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am setting array elements into my localStorage.

I click the function appendTasks here once and items are being stored correctly on localStorage for the first web session:

```
function appendTasks() {
  tasks.push(input.value);
  tasks.join(" ");
  for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
     //Add to Local Storage
    localStorage.setItem(i, tasks[i]) 
  }
```

This is how my localStorage looks like:

[image]

Once I refresh the page after adding these elements and try to add more it simply doesn't. It goes as far as adding elements on the first web session.

Anyone knows why am I seeing this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: There is a logical flaw in your code. The starting index, `i=0` should be initialized with length or stored value or 0.

Comment: You will likely find it simpler to store the whole array as JSON using a single key instead. Then when you modify the array overwrite the existing key with new JSON

Comment: thanks @charlietfl might be the case but unfortunately still unable to add more items after refreshing

Comment: When page loads you retrieve and parse the existing JSON. Then modify that array and store the whole thing again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to store the task that way but you can try something like this.
Pretty much you want to keep track of number of items added to local storage and store it as an item in local storage for that purpose.
Then each time you refresh the page you set `taskIndex` to the next index to be used.

```
function appendTasks() {
  let taskIndex = localStorage.getItem('taskIndex');
  taskIndex = taskIndex ? parseInt(taskIndex) : 0;
  
  tasks.push(input.value);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    //Add to Local Storage
    localStorage.setItem(taskIndex, tasks[i]);
    taskIndex++
  }
  localStorage.setItem('taskIndex', taskIndex);
}
```